# Jupyter Notebook display image in portrait orientation

Tags: python, markdown, jupyter-notebook

I am displaying an image in a Jupyter Notebook using the following Markdown syntax:

```
![sieve shaker](images/shaker.jpg)
```

The image was taken in portrait mode with an iPhone but when it is displayed in the notebook it appears in landscape orientation. How can I display the image in portrait orientation?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this answers your question, but you can use HTML in the markdown cell, and format the image with CSS:

```
<img style="transform: rotate(90deg); width:500px" src="images/shaker.jpg" alt="sieve shaker" title="Title text" />
```

**EDIT**

Complete example to align two images:

### Method 1: In a markdown block:

```
<img style="float:left;transform: rotate(90deg); width:300px" src="img.jpg" />
<img style="float:left;transform: rotate(90deg); width:300px" src="img.jpg" />
```

### Method 2: In a code block:

```
%%html
<style>
.inline-block {
   display: inline-block;
}

.my_img {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    width : 300px
}
</style>

<div>
    <div class="inline-block" >
        <img class="my_img" src="img.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="inline-block">
        <img  class="my_img" src="img.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Method 2 can be in a markdown block, but you will have to use inline style rather than separate css and html.

Comment: The `transform` style seems to work. I don't know if this is related or not but I can't get two images to display on the same line with this method.

Comment: One way, you can add `float: left` in the style. You can also embed images in <div>'s to align them properly as you want...

Comment: Can you add an example in your answer on how to align the images?

Comment: sure, i hope it helps. Note you can also do method 2 in a markdown block, but you will have to use inline style rather than separate css and html.